# SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement python

Tags: python, python-idle

this is my code, super simple:

```
#borders of the bbox
longmax = 15.418483 #longitude top right
longmin = 4.953142 #longitude top left
latmax = 54.869808 #latitude top 
latmin = 47.236219 #latitude bottom

#longitude
longstep = longmax - longmin 
longstepx = longstep / 1000 #longitudal steps the model shall perfom


#latitude
latstep = latmax - longmin
latstepx = latstep / 1000 #latitudal steps the model shall perform
```

I try to run in it in the Python IDLE (python 3.3) and this errormessage occurs

```
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

Removing the "#" it works just fine.

Whats wrong?!

Comment: do yourself  a favour, install and use ipython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE can only do a single statement at once, i.e. in your case: A single line. So you have to paste in all lines individually and execute them.

Comment: Aiii. How bad. alright, thank you...
Any idea why the Shell "Vico" cant run it neither?

Comment: Most REPLs can only process a single statement at once—since they are built to give you immediate feedback for every statement. You can however open the editor in IDLE (File / New File) and put in your code there.

Comment: I work in another shell then the python 3.3 IDLE and I copied and pasted it into the python idle. thats the problem

Comment: @Christian OP tried to paste in the whole code at once in IDLE, trying to execute multiple statements at once.

Comment: @ poke: I am very new to python. I create a new file in the IDL, copied and pasted my code in there. But how do I run it. When I go on "run" in my bar on top (working on a mac here) it opens another windows.

Comment: You have one window where you can enter a full script, and another window where it will run and where you can execute additional (single) statements. You can also save a `.py` file with any editor and execute it from your command line (if you don’t need the interactive console).

Comment: Ai, thanks a lot :) Now I understand. I guess we will see us around here. Getting my feet wet with python and I am pretty sure I will run into some problems since I never programmed any before :)