# If statement Python 3.3.4 syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm very new to Python and have to make a temperature converter for my class and I have the begining of it here below.  It's giving me  a syntax error on the Colon and I have tried a semi colon and a comma and have no idea what to do.  Like I said brand new to programming so any help at all would be great thanks.

```
scale = float(input("If you would like to convert to Farenheint, write '1'.     
If you would like to convert to Celcius, write '2'"))                   
if scale == 1 : print("Please print your temperature using numbers only")
```

Comment: Do you actually have a line break in the middle of the prompt? I get a different error when that is the case, but no syntax errors otherwise. That said, it is recommended that you always put start the body of the `if` statement on the following line, even if it is a short one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting a syntax error at the end of the `float` line. I'd recommend changing your quote (`"`) to a triple quote (`"""`), which indicates that you have a block string. Try this:

```
scale = float(input("""If you would like to convert to Farenheint, write '1'.     
If you would like to convert to Celcius, write '2'"""))
```

Comment: I tired that and it tells me this   ......                               SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement        Any other Ideas?

Comment: According to this question, IDLE can only do one line at a time. it may be helpful in trying to debug it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588956/syntaxerror-multiple-statements-found-while-compiling-a-single-statement-python