# im using a python book and I copied the code but it says, multiple statements found while compiling a single statement don't know what's wrong

Tags: python

```
name = input("Hi. What's your name? ")

print("name")

print("Hi,", name)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

It says multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

I'm using a book and tried many different things. Also, I'm a noob at this as you can tell. If you have any suggestions that'll be great

Comment: Are you just pasting that into the Python shell? You can only execute one line at a time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588956/syntaxerror-multiple-statements-found-while-compiling-a-single-statement-python

Comment: No, I'm using the idle for it and then i try to run it on the shell, and it just says, multiple statements found while compiling a single statement. I'm also using a python book to help me too. and I typed it over like 6 times in case I messed up but didnt.

Comment: `%paste`? if you're working in Ipython also `print("Hi,", name)` is not correct format

Comment: what is the correct format? so the book is wrong? Just wondering

Comment: It's `print("Hi, {0}".format(name))`.

Comment: If you want to use C-style formatting, you might want to try `print("Hi, %s", name))`.

Comment: I just tried it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I wanna use a python style format and im looking at the book right now and it says to type                                                                                  name = input("Hi. What's your name? ")

print("name")

print("Hi,", name)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")

Comment: What page is that from? There's a possibility that it is a typo.

Comment: @dmitrypolonskiy that is correct Python syntax

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh really? Cool! I forgot about that syntax being proper.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you being sarcastic?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is absolutely correct here. That code works fine in python 3.

Comment: Andrew, it seems you have installed Python 2. You should use Python 3 instead. Python 2 is at its official end of life in 2020.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6.0 right now but for some reason that one code is not working but the previous code worked and its the same concept but it doesn't have the input function involved. it just name = "larry" and then so on with the code

Comment: I had to update python for it to work

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, assuming you are using python 3, but you need to type (or paste) each line, one at a time. Based on what you are seeing, I suspect you are putting it all in at once, without a new line after each line.

If you are using python 2, you'll need to use `raw_input` rather than input, like this:

```
name = raw_input("Hi. What's your name? ")

print("name")

print("Hi,", name)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: I am using python 3. and I am typing it one line at a time and on a new line each time. but it still won't work but im gonna try your code and see if it works, if it does, i'll you know

Comment: the raw_input worked perfectly, I'm gonna start using that from now on if I have to do another code like this

Comment: @AndrewSmith-Hinson then you are using Python2 and doing yourself a disservice. Install and use Python 3

Comment: also, these < > are showing up on my code after I print my name, how do i get rid of it?

Comment: juanpa I download python 3.6.0 already, that's what i'm using right now

Comment: Can you add the output you are seeing to the question? Show us what you meant by `< >`?

Comment: You are not if `raw_input` is working from r you. That isn't a function in Python 3

Comment: @AndrewSmith-Hinson if raw_input worked, you aren't using python 3 somehow. `raw_input` doesn't work in python 3.6.0. Is it possible you are inadvertently running python 2? Try running things as `python3` instead of just `python`. If you are using ipython, try `ipython3` instead of `ipython`.

Comment: can you send me the link to python 3? and it will print out as <Hi, Larry>

Comment: The brackets are likely a way for your environment to indicate this is output. try putting your code in a text file, and then from a command line run `python3 whatever-your-program-is-called.py`, and see if the brackets are gone.

Comment: For what it is worth, I'd highly recommend you take a look at the free, interactive online textbook: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/index.html

Comment: Another great, shorter course that you could try is Google's short course: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/ If it seems outside of your reach, that's ok. Still worth knowing about.

Comment: I doubt you need to update it if you installed python 3.6.0. You probably just need to use `python3` and `ipython3` to be sure your system is running the correct python. It's a good idea for now to keep the python 2 installed as well for now.

Comment: To be sure, try typing the line `import sys` followed by the line `print (sys.version)` Python will print out the version that you are currently running.

Answer (score 0):

So couple of things:

`print("name")` will not print the name you captured from the last variable but a string that says `name`

`print("Hi,", name)` prints `('Hi,', 'Dmitry')` which is probably not what you want, instead do this: `', '.join(["Hi", name])` There are probably other Python 3 conventions but I work in Python 2 so I don't know them all off the top of my head.

`input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")` not sure of the purpose of this line. Seems like a stray line from a block of code and it's not being assigned to any variable. Furthermore it throws an error `SyntaxError`. What book are you using if I may ask?

Comment: im using python programming for the absolute beginner third edition. and apparently the last line with the input, suppose to make you press the enter to exit out of it. and okay, ill try that, thank you

Comment: I have never heard of that book. If you want to use a book I strongly recommend Oreilly Press. [HERE](http://stock.ethop.org/pdf/python/Learning%20Python,%205th%20Edition.pdf) is something for a beginner.

Comment: The OP is using Python 3 syntax. `print` us a function. The is a typical way of using `print`

Comment: okay, but why would make me use it in that type of way? if  it was going to become an error in the end. i type the code one line at a time and followed what the book told me but it still came out as a error

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy `print("name")` puts an identifier above the line containing the name. I suspect it's for the purposes of example in a beginner book.  `print("Hi,", name)` works just fine in python 3, which based on the use of `input()` is what this code is intended for. `('Hi,', 'Dmitry')` is what will happen in python 2. `input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")` is clearly intended to pause the program until the user enters data (eg, a carriage return) to exit. None of these points you raise are correct. His code is fine for beginner python 3.

Comment: @Chris Larson, I type the example code from the book and every time I would try to run it, it won't work. it will say, Hi, what's your name? and I will print my name and after that it doesn't work and these < > will show up on the code too. which I'm trying to get rid of

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Python version in the **HELP>about IDLE** tab of IDLE editor or Shell  - you seem to be using python 2 as others have stated

If you are able to enter and run one line of code at a time, followed by the next line then you are using the Shell,  not the IDLE editor

You should be able to paste the code you have in question into IDLE editor and run (F5) - you should be prompted to save before it is run in the Shell.