# Why am I getting SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement?

Tags: python

[image]

I just started learning Python a few weeks ago so I'm fairly new to Python. I'm trying to write a code that takes in user's numbers and turn them into a letter based grade. After finding the average of the user's input I want a letter based grade for the average as well. Here's my code

```
def scores():
    get_scores = []
    for i in range(5):
        get_grades.append(input("Enter your 5 grades and positive numbers"))
    print(get_grades)


def calculate_Average(get_scores):
    average = (get_scores) / 5
    return average


def assign_grade(get_scores):
    if (get_score < 60):
        return "F"
    elif (get_score < 70):
        return "D"
    elif (get_score < 80):
        return "C"
    elif (get_score < 90):
        return "B"
    elif (get_score < 100):
        return "A"
```

For some reason when I try to run the code I kept on getting SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: What is `get_grades`?

Comment: It's a place where I store user's input

Comment: The code you've posted is syntactically correct (albeit probably not functional or there are some globals hanging around that you aren't showing). How are you invoking your code to get that error?

Comment: What do you mean by how are you invoking your code? I'm fairly new so I'm not really understanding what you mean. Also, that's all the code I've wrote.

Comment: @Xiao Welcome to SO! Can you please paste the full traceback? (The error message, including the line number)

Comment: @oldbunny2800 I added an image link to my post instead because it looks like there's a new problem now

Comment: 1. in your first function, your get_scores 'transformed' in to 'get_grades' .   2. in your assign_grade, get_scores is the input but you reference it by 'get_score'

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like you literally typed `>>>` at the beginning (after the _prompt_, which is the `>>>` that the Python interpreter produces), which you should not do.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset I tried to remove the >>> but it won't allow me

Comment: @Xiao You need to copy and paste. You can't edit code you've already run in IDLE

Comment: @OldBunny2800 When ever I open IDLE, it just starts with >>>. Even after I paste    the code, it just stays there.

Comment: Only paste the part of the code that doesn't have the >>>. If IDLE automatically adds it it's fine.

Comment: @oldbunny2800 Okay thanks for the tip :)

Comment: You are fundamentally misunderstanding how IDLE works.  You should create a new file window (from the File menu), and enter your code there - you can then edit the code freely, save it to disk, and run it whenever you want to.  The Shell window is for trying simple things, and examining the state left by a script you ran.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588956/syntaxerror-multiple-statements-found-while-compiling-a-single-statement-python)